# Convert AsIs to numeric separated by coma in data frame

Tags: r

I have such data frame:

```
structure(list(P1 = c("Mark", "Katrin", "Kate", "Hank", "Tom", 
"Marcus"), P2 = c("Tim", "Greg", "Seba", "Teqa", "Justine", "Monica"
), clique = structure(list(`930` = integer(0), `2090` = integer(0), 
    `3120` = c(2L, 3L, 231L), `3663` = integer(0), `3704` = integer(0), 
    `4156` = c(19L, 27L)), .Names = c("930", "2090", "3120", 
"3663", "3704", "4156"), class = "AsIs")), .Names = c("P1", "P2", 
"clique"), row.names = c(930L, 2090L, 3120L, 3663L, 3704L, 4156L
), class = "data.frame")
```

And I have a problem with the last column called `clique`. I would like to convert this column to numeric values separated by come in one column or the best option would be to transform `integer(0)` to NAs and put the numbers in separate columns. Just keep one number in each column.
I will accept both solutions.

example data:

```
P1  P2  clique
Mark    Tim integer(0)
Katrin  Greg    integer(0)
Kate    Seba    c(2, 3, 231)
Hank    Teqa    integer(0)
Tom Justine integer(0)
Marcus  Monica  c(19, 27)

> class(data$clique)
[1] "AsIs"
```

Desired output:

```
 P1      P2    clique
Mark     Tim      NA    
Katrin   Greg     NA    
Kate     Seba    2,3,231
Hank     Teqa     NA
Tom      Justine  NA    
Marcus   Monica  19,27
```

or

```
P1      P2    clique New_column1 New_column2
Mark    Tim          
Katrin  Greg          
Kate    Seba      2        3          231
Hank    Teqa          
Tom     Justine          
Marcus  Monica    19       27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `listCol_w` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
listCol_w(mydf, "clique")[, lapply(.SD, as.numeric), by = .(P1, P2)]
##        P1      P2 clique_fl_1 clique_fl_2 clique_fl_3
## 1:   Mark     Tim          NA          NA          NA
## 2: Katrin    Greg          NA          NA          NA
## 3:   Kate    Seba           2           3         231
## 4:   Hank    Teqa          NA          NA          NA
## 5:    Tom Justine          NA          NA          NA
## 6: Marcus  Monica          19          27          NA
```

I recommend this because you mentioned you wanted the numeric values. You won't be able to store a value like "2,3,231" as a numeric value.

If you still want to try the approach of collapsing the values and then splitting them, you can try:

```
mydf$clique <- vapply(mydf$clique, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ","), character(1L))
```

The `str` would show that you now have a single character string instead of a `list` of character vectors. You can then use `cSplit` on that to get the wide form.

```
> str(mydf)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ P1    : chr  "Mark" "Katrin" "Kate" "Hank" ...
 $ P2    : chr  "Tim" "Greg" "Seba" "Teqa" ...
 $ clique: chr  "" "" "2,3,231" "" ...
```

Comment: I was using your package for spliting values separated by coma in another script that's why I would accept the first option as well. Of course values separated by coma can't be stored as numeric. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ShaxiLiver, OK. I updated to show how you could do the first option as well.